# ArcGIS RunTime for .net Local server pattern

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm completely new in RunTime and also in any kind of programming.

I'm working on an app for Windows tablets which needs to:

- have aerials as a basemap
- work in an offline environment
- have editable feature class (adding lines in the field)
- edits doesn't need to be sync when online (client doesn't have ArcGIS Server etc.)
- edited feature class needs to be export to shp.

I'm not sure if Local Service pattern is a good choice? 
I choose it because I'll need geoprocessing tool to be able to extract fc to shp. 
Also our client will once a month provide updated data for people in the field. Because of  no option of sharing trough ArcGIS service, I've been thinking about sharing it through mpk. The newest mpk will always replace the old one.

Can anyone tell me which way is the best? I had a look at many samples but there are not really any for the local server pattern.

Comment: extract fc to shp? sorry, what do you mean for fc?

Comment: Sorry...I mean feature class. We need to be able to edit polyline feature class (as it's impossible to edit shapefile) and then extract this polylines to shp.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a geoprocessing local server to extract the features from a shapefile, you can do it using an [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Layers_FeatureLayer.htm), so, if you require to make the changes in the features and save it as shp file, maybe you need a third party (I have been using DotSpatial).

Taking into account what you wrote, I will take the package option (.mpk file) due is straight forward for the API, it allows the edition operations and let the client add visualization options to the package (saving time in the offline application).

I'm more experienced in ArcGIS runtime SDK for WPF, I'm not quite sure if the .NET runtime includes the capabilities to save a shp file, as I already told you, a third party could handle the job.